# Openvpn Authentication Failed after adding Google Authentication in MFA

Tags: openvpn, google-authenticator, multi-factor-authentication

I am using tunnelblick to connect to my VPN server, and I can successfully connect to my VPN with username and password but I wanted to add MFA to add extra layer of security and I followed the below link and I could successfully setup the MFA. But while entering my username and password it's not popped up for MFA token. I tried to pass pass and token together but still it's throwing invalid credential.

Ref Link [Link I followed to setup MFA](https://www.howtoforge.com/securing-openvpn-with-a-one-time-password-otp-on-ubuntu)

Please help me to provide to MFA in right way if I am not correct or if I am missing anything.

In Client Config :

```
auth-user-pass
```

Comment: This solution works, Check This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606921/failed-to-authenticate-w-google-authenticator-when-configuring-openvpn-on-openw/64415499#64415499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at tha /var/log/auth.log, I found there was some permission issue in accessing the .google_authenticator. After changing the permission it's working fine.